# What is the definition of the integral of a differential form on a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a smooth oriented manifold of dimension $n$. Let $\alpha = \alpha_{[0]} + \alpha_{[1]} + ...+ \alpha_{[n]}$ be smooth differential form on $M$  such that $\alpha_{[I]} \in \mathcal{A}^i(M)$. By definition, we have
$$\int_M \alpha := \int_M \alpha_{[n]}.$$

Suppose that $N$ is submanifold of $M$ of dimension $k$. How is the integral of $\alpha$ on $N$ defined, is it $\int_N \alpha = \int_N \alpha_{[k]}$ ?

Comment: I guess that's the only sensible definition. But can you provide more context? In what situation did you see this?

Comment: @Arctic Char, I was wondering about this, while I was learning about localization theorem in equavariant cohomology which calculate the integral of an equavariant differential form $\alpha:=\alpha_{[0]} +...+ \alpha_{[n]}$ using $\alpha_{[0]}$.

Comment: Any comment please ?